# Deploy django with apache, django channels 3 and daphne in wss

Tags: django, apache, django-channels, daphne, asgi

> Os Ubuntu 20 LTS

i have a problem with my project in production, and i don't understand where and whats it's going wrong, thease are the files and the responses:

#### *000-default.conf:*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

.....

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site.addns.org [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.site.addns.org
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* wss://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
    ProxyPass /wss/ wss://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /wss/ wss://127.0.0.1:8000/



</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
.....


     ProxyPreserveHost On
     SSLProxyEngine on
     SSLProxyVerify none
     SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
     SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8000%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
    ProxyPass /wss/ wss://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse /wss/ wss://127.0.0.1:8000/
    


</VirtualHost>
```

#### *asgi.py:*

```
import os

from django.urls import re_path, path
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "produzione.settings")
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.routing import get_default_application
from principale import consumers

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,

    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            path(r'wss/$', consumers.EchoConsumer.as_asgi()),
            path(r'ws/chat/$', consumers.EchoConsumer.as_asgi()),
        ])
    ),
})
```

#### *consumers.py:*

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

from channels.consumer import AsyncConsumer

class EchoConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
```

#### *settings.py:*

```
...
ASGI_APPLICATION = "produzione.asgi.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 8000)],
        },
    },
}
...
```

#### *js file:*

```
    var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
    var chat_socket = new WebSocket(ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + '/wss/');

    var chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            'wss://'
            + '127.0.0.1:8000'
            + '/wss'
        );
```

#### *js response:*

> This error appear instantly on browser console

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.addns.org/wss/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

> This error appear instantly on error.log file:

```
Not Found: /wss/
```

> This after a few seconds on browser console

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8000/wss' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out
```

#### *daphne command:*

`sudo daphne -e ssl:8001:privateKey=privkey.pem:certKey=cert.pem produzione.asgi:application -b 127.0.0.1`

#### *daphne response after lunch:*

```
2021-02-11 14:03:42,587 INFO     Starting server at ssl:8001:privateKey=privkey.pem:certKey=cert.pem, tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2021-02-11 14:03:42,587 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
2021-02-11 14:03:42,588 INFO     Configuring endpoint ssl:8001:privateKey=privkey.pem:certKey=cert.pem
2021-02-11 14:03:42,592 INFO     Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8001
2021-02-11 14:03:42,592 INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2021-02-11 14:03:42,593 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
```